# Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services how to get data from AD DS

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I just recently started working with Lightweight Directory Services and I have read many articles but I still have few questions.

**My objective is to authenticate users in application using Lightweight Directory Services.**

To accomplish the objective I installed Lightweight Directory services using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2011/09/16/ftp-and-ldap-part-2-how-to-set-up-an-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-ad-lds-server.aspx) tutorial.

After completing the steps in the tutorial I was able successfully connect to it using *ADSI Edit.*

However, as I started looking around I see that this instance is empty. There're no user objects.

I have a full version of Active Directory (2008 R2) installed in my production. How do I get the user data from full version to Lightweight so I can do authentication?

Can this be accomplished using the approach I'm taking, or I'm misunderstanding the concept of Lightweight Directory Services?

Is the concept to validate users in Lightweight Directory Services similar as I would authenticate users through the full version of AD, like the code below?

```
public string Authenticate(string username, string pwd)
    {
        string domain = "mydomain";
        using (PrincipalContext ad = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            bool isValid = ad.ValidateCredentials(username, pwd);
            string result = isValid.ToString();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Note* full active directory is in production sitting behind the firewall, while Lightweight Directory Services is residing in DMZ on the other side of firewall.

Comment: have you thought about perhaps a different approach.. I will post an example of what I currently use that works just fine also why don't you change the method signature to return a `boolean` so you don't have to convert the result to its `string` representation

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions. This is just to show the work I have done so far. What I'm really curious about is how I can get users authenticate (and get their info) from Lightweight Directory Services when they only exists in Full Version of Active Directory. How does Lightweight AD communicates with AD DS? Thanks.

Comment: No suggestions at all?

Comment: the only thing I can suggest since you are outside of the `DMZ` is reading this link perhaps it will lend some ideas 
[Accessing Lightweight outside the DMZ](http://www.44342.com/dotnet-framework-f1218-t3267-p1.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fullName = string.Empty;
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,"racerX")) //User.Identity.Name
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            fullName = user.DisplayName;
        }
    }
}
```

- if the user is in AD then you know that they are validated assuming that their account is properly maintained as well..

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have no issues validating user against AD. But my application will be sitting behind the firewall and I can't directly talk to AD. I have to use Lightweight AD to accomplish this. Could you please explain how that will work? Thanks...